# Youtube-api verify app oauth for uploading yt videos from disk

Tags: python, video, google-api, upload, youtube-api

I have some troubles verifying my app for uploading videos to youtube using python. 
I have searched already for similar questions, but most seem very old and not up to date.
For verifying my "app" i need to submit it to google for verification, since the api needs special permissions to upload a video. (../auth/youtube.upload)

I would like to be using this available script from google to upload a video:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video?hl=de

But the verification of my app asks me for authorized domains, data protection url.
I dont know what to insert into this blanks, since this is not my code but just a simple example code from google itself to upload a video.

If someone could guide me to the right direction, i would appreciate any help.

[problem.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjAHu.jpg)